# including external JS for a specific view in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing

I am trying to use Ruby on Rails to build my first website.

I have read about the asset pipeline and I have a specific view that needs to reference 3 JS libraries that no other files need to reference.

I don't want to use them as `require` directives in the `assets/javascripts` manifest because than they would end up on all of the other pages that don't need them.

So, I thought I could simply include them in the view template.

---

However, I am getting **404: file not found** errors.

This is how I am including them in the template `/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/lib/assets/javascripts/three.js" %>          
<%= javascript_include_tag "/lib/assets/javascripts/perlin.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/lib/assets/javascripts/cube.js" %>
```

This is being rendered as the first lines inside of `<body>` tags (this is because the code in the template is rendered according to a yield tag in `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` and that `yield` tag is placed inside `body` tags)

As you can see, the files are located in `lib/assets/javascripts` and I am trying to access them by using the full path (relative to the web-root).

---

This is an example of an error message that gets generated on the server when trying to render one of the libraries:

```
Started GET "/lib/assets/javascripts/three.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-15 11:30:52 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/lib/assets/javascripts/three.js"):
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /home/luke/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/luke/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/luke/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

---

### Edit

People are suggesting that I move my files. Can you please explain why I can't have them in `lib`? The docs say that `lib/assets` is where libs should go and I concur with this organization.

- The `/public` directory thing is only kept around for backwards compatibility from what I have read  (it isn't even created by default anymore)

Comment: Put your JS files to `public` directory instead of `lib/assets`. So, in case of `public/three.js` you can download it use `/three.js` relative URL path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your Javascript in `/app/assets/javascripts` and you'll be able to include it like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'file-name' %>
```

Please note that you **shouldn't** include the extension. Rails will find it for you.

Each controller has it's own Javascript and CSS files, using them is a good idea.

Be warned that if you add more assets, you'll have to add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( [file name] )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

Libs isn't *exactly* for what you think, and using public **is** a bad idea...
It's best just to put it in `/app/assets/javascripts`, as I've said.

Comment: I know I don't have to include the extension, but why shouldn't I?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Rails doesn't like it when you do, also, it means less code. Less code == Good

Comment: Do you know why I can't use absolute paths to files outside of app/assets?

Comment: Because Rails doesn't serve all of the app, just what it is told to.

Comment: If you put it in the public folder, you should be able to use absolute paths, but then you aren't using the asset pipeline, so you should just use `<script>` tags

Comment: welcome.js will ONLY be loaded when I am in the welcome view right? And that's not something configured via manifests correct? that's just default rails behavior that's setup when the controller is generated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73021/discussion-between-lukep-and-penne12).

Comment: @LukeP, not exactly, any view within the welcome controller *should* have `welcome.js` in it

Answer (score 0):

You can put the JS files in /assets/javascripts (forexample.js) and just call it in the view like this

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'forexample' %>
```

All the require javascripts files are linked only with application.js, just don't include

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

in the other views.